# How to animate transforms one by one in snap.svg ?

Tags: css, svg, transform, snap.svg, svg-animate

In this snap.svg animation indent to transform the element to **up** then **right** Is there best way to implement two transforms animate one by one ?

```
hand.animate({
  transform: 't0,-80',
  transform: 't40,-80'
}, 400);
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/epoQmr

Comment: Just use the callback feature like in the example posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use callback for the second animation

```
hand.animate({transform: 't0,-50'}, 800, function () {
    hand.animate({transform: 't50,-50'}, 800)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v170mgxa/